# Run a little HTTP server to check callback

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I would like to run a script that will create a simple HTTP server and run a function for each request.

I am using Python to test an API that should give me a callback.
For now, I am using http://requestb.in/ to test the callback, but I would like to test it directly in my python script.

Is it possible to run a callback server bind on localhost:6548 and test something base on a request?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`wsgiref`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html) to host a simple WSGI web application. Example:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import datetime

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    retval = [
            str(environ),
            "\n",
            "Hello world!\n",
            str(datetime.datetime.now())
            ]
    return retval

make_server('localhost', 6548, application).serve_forever()
```

This code creates a Python [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) web application and serves that app on `http://localhost:6548`.

Comment: Does `make_server` block the script? Is there a way to run it in a thread?

Comment: ``serve_forever()`` is a blocking call. Yes, you can run it in a thread, use the threading module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) micro framework. Here is a quick example:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/firs_call', methods=['POST'])
def first_callback():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.data
        client_ip = request.remote_addr

    return "OK"


@app.route('/second_call', methods=['GET'])
def second_callback():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         #....
         pass

    return "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run("127.0.0.1")
```

You can reach this web application at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`